# i am not able to see arabic letters while using pl sql developer

Tags: sql

I am not able to see Arabic letters while using pl sql developer

In one database, its showing correctly, but when I query in another its not coming up.

Is there anything to change in settings ? if anyone knew please let me know !!!

Answer (score 0):

Might be datatype on the other database in not the NVARCHAR. Please make sure that it is nvarchar datatype in the other database also.

Comment: both its nvarchar :(...cudnt sort out

Comment: Also 1 more thing. please check the datatype in the procedure that is used to transfer your database.